Move Pointer Register into AL
I have a pointer register, edx, and it gets set by the following instruction:
mov edx, stringvar
where
stringvar is defined with stringvar: db "teststring", 0xA, 0xD, 0
so edx contains the memory address of the first byte in stringvar, "t"
but when I go to print it
mov ah, 0x0E
mov al, [edx]
int 0x10

it prints "☰"
what is this code actually doing?

You probably did not set up ds properly.

over in the bootloader i have
mov ax, 0 mov ds, ax

Then your org does not match.

It turns out I improperly set the org
I copied the code from the bootloader
org 0x7C00
instead of
org 0x7E00, the position in memory the kernel starts at
